# Is it possible to cast an element directly to an Array?

Tags: c#, casting

Is there a way to cast a single object of `T` to an `T[]`

An example of where this would be used is in while passing a single `string` to a functions that requires a `string[]`

example

```
void ExistingMethod(string[] sa);
void main()
{
  string s;
  ExistingMethod(s); //<= problem is there a syntax that allows this type of cast?
}
```

not interested in a solution like this

```
string [] singleElementArray = new string[1];
singleElementArray[0] = s;
ExistingMethod(singleElementArray)
```

I'm looking to see if C# allows this type of casting.

I thought I saw a way that Java allows it by simply wrapping it like this `([s])` with the []. Does C# have this type of syntax?

Note, NOT interested in creating an array of 1 and assigning it...

Comment: `foo(new[] {s})` is probably the shortest.

Comment: Consider instead to add `void foo(string s)` - you'd be able to deal with conversion in a way your code find useful and have code that calls one of the function to look as if there is magical conversion you want.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's from a class library.

Comment: I changed title to match your last comment - feel free to edit/revert. (But don't put tags in title...)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  - Thank you for the input, I have added and changed the title to directly reflect that exact question and answer.  As for the tags, is there a specific reason not to add tags to the title?  Seems more beneficial since this question is directly related to C# and not another language?

Comment: There are several discussion on meta about it - general consensus: tags already there to indicate it (easily searchable/sortable), adding to title is unnecessary duplication - i.e. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no cast to allow this, but you can create an array on the fly with

```
string s = "blah";
foo(new [] { s });
```

Comment: @vcsjones you gave the info first but didn't answer the question, only commented :(

Answer (score 13):

Change `foo(string[] sa)` to `foo(params string[] sa)`.

`params` lets you put an array that takes an array parameter parameter array like so : `foo(foo, bar, baz);` instead of `foo(new[]{foo, bar, baz});`

Or you could do a `.Arr<T>(this T obj)` function, which returns a `T[]`. Something like this:

```
public static T[] Arr<T>(this T obj)
{
return new[]{ obj };
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
foo(obj.Arr());
```

Comment: I like this suggestion, can you provide more details as to what this does and how it helps the asker?

Comment: params lets you put a parameter array like so : foo(s, a, b) instead of foo(new[]{s, a, b}).

Comment: @ofstream, add your comment to your post above.

Comment: Cant change the foo()  it is part of a library

Comment: The function takes a array of strings and does file processing on each  path in the array and returns a different array of strings.  I only have one passed in string from a higher calling functions...

Comment: @vbbartlett Then I'm afraid you can't do much but the ones below, or just make a wrapper, like this: public void foo(params string[] array) { foo(array); }

Comment: Someplace I saw code that in Java that seemed allow a single element to be cast as an array, (in C++ i would use the & opperator) but C# arrays have other properties like size that makes the array in C# nice to use.

Comment: Note that this is just wrapping the single object into an array for you; but the object is still being wrapped in an array.

Comment: @ofstream It *compiles*.  We don't have sufficient requirements to know if it *works*, especially given that he seems real opposed to explicitly creating a one item array.  If wrapping the item in an array causes problems for some reason, this doesn't solve that.

Comment: No, he just doesn't want to do the little bit of extra typing it seems.

Comment: @ofstream  thank you both for the comments!  I am always concerned with performance and any ramification, but im also lazy when it comes to typing.  So both comments are well received.  Because of other requirements, too long to explain, but I would have to type this type of casting out multiple times and wanted an easy way and wanted to understand the finer details of C#. I know c++ in DETAIL, but not C#.  Thanks to all for the input

Comment: @vbbartlett, if foo() is part of a library, then your syntax is invalid. You need either a class or a instance qualifier. Do you have any real code you could show?

Comment: @Zano It's just an example.

Comment: @ofstream: Sure, it's just not an example of his problem. Since he states that foo() is part of a library he doesn't control, the example does not show that.

Comment: @Zano  you are correct...  it would be Class.method(string[] paths), but the reality of it is, it doesn't matter, the casting syntax of C# is what the basis of the question is about.

Comment: @vbbartlett, yes it does, check my answer.

Comment: @Zano, but the question really is Can you directly cast a <T> to a <T> [] and the answer is no, you need to new <T> {t} where T is the type and t is an instance of that type.

Comment: @vbbartlett, in that case the answer really isn't no, it's "it depends on T". It's trivial to write a T that allows that cast. But, for the general case, you're right, it can't be done. Maybe you could use Perl instead? :-)

Comment: @Zano just learning the finer details of the syntax of this language, and again you are correct, generally it looks like it can't be done.

Answer (score 2):

C# has following syntax:

```
foo(new[] { s });
```

Answer (score 2):

No, a single string is not an array of strings, so it wouldn't make sense to cast it to an array. The simplest thing you can do here is:

```
void foo(string[] sa);
void main()
{
  string s = "some value"; // A string must have a value before you can use it
  foo(new[]{ s }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you state in a comment that foo() is part of a library that you can't modify, and assuming that foo() is an instance method, you could extend it to accept exactly the syntax you want.

Example original implementation of foo() in class Bar:

```
class Bar {
    public void foo(string[] s) {
        foreach (var s1 in s) {
            Console.WriteLine(s1);                
        }
    }
}
```

Your extension of foo():

```
static class BarExtensions {
    public static void foo(this Bar bar, string s) {
        bar.foo(new[] {s});
    }
}
```

Your example call, modified to use an external class:

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var bar = new Bar();
        string s = "hello";
        bar.foo(s); // This is how you wanted to call it 
    }
}
```

Comment: I definitely could do something like that but again I am interested in casting and the syntax of the language.